# SelectionColor equivalent in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am converting my application from WinFrom to WPF. I want equivalent to WPF of following line of code :

```
txtbox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: Maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246795/change-selection-color-of-wpf-listviewitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SelectionBrush` for WPF -

```
textBox.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Or simply -

```
textBox.SelectionBrush = Brushes.Green;
```

---

Changing `textBox highlighted text color` is `not possible` in WPF. Check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850629/how-to-change-the-highlighted-texts-foreground-color-for-a-wpf-textbox/10850718#10850718) for more details.

However you can achieve that for `RixhTextBox` though. Details can be found here - [Change selected text color in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015380/how-can-i-change-the-selected-text-background-color-in-rich-text-box-wpf-c-sharp).

Comment: But SelectionBrush highlighting the text I want to change color of  text !

Comment: That's not possible for TextBox. Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850629/how-to-change-the-highlighted-texts-foreground-color-for-a-wpf-textbox/10850718#10850718).

Comment: However you can do that for RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1):

just do  something like  this  in  your xaml code

```
 <TextBox SelectionBrush="Green"/>
```

or  in  your code behind

```
   txtBox.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Comment: But SelectionBrush highlighting the text I want to change color of  text !

Comment: @daniyalahmad if txtbox is a TextBox, look at the Foreground property